# Recreate My Git Repo From this Commit Json file

Tags: json, git, github

So I messed up, bit time. I force pushed a new git repo over my existing one. I never should have done that. I was able to recover this json file that has the text of all of my files in it. How can I recreate my git repo or get all the files out in a readable format?

[commit.json](https://api.github.com/repos/MeadeRobert/PicoCTF2017/commits/0efa07574fd0568477c967a355b408c6f1bcfb08)

I am currently trying to regex my data out of the json fields. but the \n+ are getting in the way. I need to also convert the \n's to actual new lines. I will update this as I make progress. But an easy way to convert the json to a repo would be amazing.

Comment: How did you recover that file? Maybe whatever generated it has the original commits. Also, do you have the original repository at all? Even if it's been rebased, the original commits are still probably there.

Comment: Weastie tried what you suggested and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all your data is here: https://github.com/MeadeRobert/PicoCTF2017/tree/0efa07574fd0568477c967a355b408c6f1bcfb08

I just followed a link on the JSON.